# Change the key value in XML using Python

Tags: python, xml

I need to modify the **online_hostname** key value in XML using python. I tried xml element tree but it does not work.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = xml_tree.getroot()
root[0][0] = "requiredvalue"
```

test.xml file is as below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<bzinfo>
    <myidentity online_hostname="testdevice-air_2022_01_25" 
                bzlogin="me@abc.com" />
</bzinfo>
```

Error:

```
IndexError: child assignment index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much better to explicitly search the required node (`find` will do in this case) instead of using indexes on the `root` node:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = xml_tree.getroot()

myidentity_node = root.find('myidentity')
myidentity_node.attrib['online_hostname'] = 'required_value'

xml_tree.write('modified.xml')
```

modified.xml after running this code:

```xml
<bzinfo>
    <myidentity bzlogin="me@abc.com" online_hostname="required_value" />
</bzinfo>
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. Can we do the same in bash script?

Comment: Can we do the same in bash script? We are finding issues with Python Mac? Thanks.